# How can I remove unprintable hex characters in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SSIS process that creates an xml file for me.
The data contains of several fields, one of them is a product name (varchar).
Some of the names contain hexadecimal characters that appear in an unwanted way in the xml file. For example: x1F, x1E, x18, x19. The problem is that the some names look like 'Product**x1F**Name' etc.
SSMS seems to handle them normally, but not the XML editor / parser.

Is there any way I could easily detect and replace the unwanted characters within the query?

Any tips will be strongly appreciated

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the actual problem is. Please edit your question to include an example varchar value, the output of that using cast(ProductName as varbinary), as well as the actual XML output. If they're actually unprintable characters (e.g.: ASCII values 0-31) it may be helpful to include a hexadecimal dump of the XML, which you could do using Visual Studio Code with the "hexdump for VSCode" extension (for example).

Comment: Well, I just checked it out and they're infact ASCII values 0-31 (its actually 30 and 31 that appear the most)

Comment: Well. I managed to solve my problem using replace() for char(30) and char(31), as those were the ones that appeared the most in my case. Thanks for the suggestion